# Python 3, How to differentiate function and class the first time you use it

Tags: python-3.x

Having this question for a while.

whenever we use a new module that we haven't used before.

Is there a way to tell if it is a function in this module or a class in this module without checking documentation?

or most of the time, we just do not care what type it is, we just use it

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for information on introspection? 14.2 addresses this specific issue. https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/object_introspection.html

Comment: Most of the time you don't care. But you should always read the documentation because that's always the best way to understand a third party library, and its public API.